# How to SELECT by MAX(date)?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, max

This is the table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `reports` (
  `report_id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `computer_id` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `date_entered` datetime NOT NULL default '1970-01-01 00:00:00',
  `total_seconds` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `iphone_id` int(11) default '0',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`report_id`),
  KEY `computer_id` (`computer_id`),
  KEY `iphone_id` (`iphone_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=120990 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

I need a `SELECT` statement that will list the `report_id` per `computer_id` from latest entered `date_entered`, and I have no clue how to do that.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

This should do it:

```
SELECT report_id, computer_id, date_entered
FROM reports AS a
WHERE date_entered = (
    SELECT MAX(date_entered)
    FROM reports AS b
    WHERE a.report_id = b.report_id
      AND a.computer_id = b.computer_id
)
```

Comment: Almost. I left out "a.report_id = b.report_id" and that did the trick. Thank you

Comment: This is a little inefficient because you are generating too many subqueries.
Instead, try to use a uncorrelated subquery.
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html

Comment: Pablo is correct. The filtering can be done earlier by joining a subquery, thus saving performance.

Answer (score 19):

Are you only wanting it to show the last date_entered, or to order by starting with the last_date entered?

```
SELECT report_id, computer_id, date_entered
FROM reports
GROUP BY computer_id
ORDER BY date_entered DESC
-- LIMIT 1 -- uncomment to only show the last date.
```

Comment: When id do this, I get the wrong report_id. I checked the statement with a WHERE computer_id = 30. The result was the first report_id of all found report_ids in combination with the latest date_entered

Answer (score 5):

Accordig to this: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=54784 casting as char should do the trick:

```
SELECT report_id, computer_id, MAX(CAST(date_entered AS CHAR))
FROM reports
GROUP BY report_id, computer_id
```

Comment: This will get you the max date, but not necessarily the other values from the same row.

Answer (score 5):

This is a very old question but I came here due to the same issue, so I am leaving this here to help any others.

I was trying to optimize the query because it was taking over 5 minutes to query the DB due to the amount of data. My query was similar to the accepted answer's query. [Pablo's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7836036/how-to-select-by-maxdate#comment77414530_7836444) pushed me in the right direction and my 5 minute query became 0.016 seconds. So to help any others that are having very long query times try using an [uncorrelated subquery](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html).

The example for the OP would be:

```
SELECT 
    a.report_id, 
    a.computer_id, 
    a.date_entered
FROM reports AS a
    JOIN (
        SELECT report_id, computer_id, MAX(date_entered) as max_date_entered
        FROM reports
        GROUP BY report_id, computer_id
    ) as b
WHERE a.report_id = b.report_id
    AND a.computer_id = b.computer_id
    AND a.date_entered = b.max_date_entered
```

Thank you [Pablo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2354818/pablo)  for the comment. You saved me big time!

Answer (score 4):

This would work perfectely, if you are using current timestamp

```
SELECT * FROM reports WHERE date_entered = (SELECT max(date_entered) FROM REPORTS)
```

This would also work, if you are not using current timestamp but you are using date and time column seperately

```
SELECT * FROM reports WHERE date_entered = (SELECT max(date_entered) FROM REPORTS) ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 1):

**Workaround but working solution**

Only if ID is autoincrement, you can search for the maximum id instead of the max date.
So, by the ID you can find all others fields.

```
select *
from table
where id IN ( 
              select max(id)
              from table
              group by #MY_FIELD#
              )
```

Answer (score 1):

Works perfect for me:

```
(SELECT content FROM tblopportunitycomments WHERE opportunityid = 1 ORDER BY dateadded DESC LIMIT 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select report_id, computer_id, date_entered
into #latest_date
from reports a
where exists(select 'x' from reports 
                where a.report_id = report_id
                group by report_id having max(date_entered) =   a.date_entered)

select * from #latest_leave where computer_id = ##
```

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation.

Answer (score 0):

If you sort the table by date_entered descending, grouping collects the correct rows:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT report_id, computer_id, date_entered ORDER BY date_entered DESC
) sorted 
GROUP BY computer_id
```

This fully pages in the indices (assuming you indexed all three columns - otherwise full table scan), but if your indices are on HDD that will often be the fastest solution.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT report_id, computer_id, date_entered
FROM reports
WHERE date_entered = (
    SELECT date_entered 
    FROM reports 
    ORDER date_entered 
    DESC LIMIT 1
)
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Answer (score -1):

Did this on a blog engine to get the latest blog. I adapted it to your table structure.

```
SELECT * FROM reports WHERE date_entered = (SELECT max(date_entered) FROM REPORTS)
```

Answer (score -1):

It works great for me

```
SELECT
    report_id,computer_id,MAX(date_entered)
FROM
    reports
GROUP BY
    computer_id
```

Comment: I don't know why this got upvoted. It is wrong. There can be many report_id per computer_id. You don't tell the DBMS which you want. MySQL should throw an error. It does so, provided you `SET sql_mode = 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY';` as you should. If you don't, MySQ will silently aply `ANY_VALUE(report_id)`, so the returned report_id can come from any row in the group. It gets arbitrarily picked, and the query is not deterministic.

Answer (score -2):

I use this solution **`having max(date_entered)`** and it works very well

```
SELECT 
  report_id, 
  computer_id, 
  date_entered
FROM reports
GROUP BY computer_id having max(date_entered)
```

Comment: This didn't work for me, still getting the first value, not the max