# MYSQL delete all records except first and last for a given date

Tags: mysql, database, bash

This gives me all the records for a particular switch and port. I would like to delete all except the first and last one for each day.

```
/mysql -sN --user=root --password=notmypassword -e 
"SELECT * FROM collector.fibre 
WHERE fabric_switch_name = 'switch-1' 
  AND port = '0' 
  AND datatype = 'TxElements' 
  AND (time > '2016-05-31 00:00:00' AND time < '2016-05-31 23:59:59') "
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how much time will it take to delete all this records but i think 
minutes of works just wait for it :

```
delete fb from collector.fibre fb 
INNER JOIN 
(
SELECT 
  distinct 
  f.id -- extract only the ids 
FROM 
  collector.fibre  f
  INNER JOIN (
    -- create a special table   day   min_time  max_time 
    select 
      date(time) as 'day',
      min(time) as 'min_time',
      max(time) as 'max_time'
    from 
      collector.fibre
     Where
        -- must be the same set of records 
        -- because we look for a dates of this switch
       fabric_switch_name = 'switch-1' 
       AND port = '0' 
       AND datatype = 'TxElements'
    group by date(time)
  )  fd on date(f.time) = fd.day  -- join the two table to have a special table see example down  
WHERE 
  fabric_switch_name = 'switch-1' 
  AND port = '0' 
  AND datatype = 'TxElements' 
  -- extract record witch the time is not
  -- the min or the max of that date 
  AND (f.time <> fd.min_time and f.time <> fd.max_time) 
) recs on fb.id = recs.id -- join the table and the result of query by the id now you will remove the records that exist in the result of the query
```

Comment: It looks like I have to manually select the database or I get "ERROR 1046 (3D000): No database selected"

Comment: No worries I can either use database name in the command or add use database name; in the first line.

Answer (score 1):

by "*first and last*" I will assume you mean ***earliest and latest***, so:

- Select criteria in the given date and then deselect the minimum date and maximum date values.

> It is assumed your time is stored in a `DATETIME` column.

```
    DELETE FROM collector.fibre 
         WHERE fabric_switch_name = 'switch-1' 
         AND port = '0' 
         AND datatype = 'TxElements' 
         AND (TIME(time) != 
             (
             SELECT MAX(TIME(time))
             FROM `collector`.`fibre` WHERE fabric_switch_name = 'switch-1' 
             AND port = '0' 
             AND datatype = 'TxElements'
             AND DATE(time) = '2016-05-30'
             )
             AND
             TIME(time) != (
             SELECT MIN(TIME(time))
             FROM `collector`.`fibre` WHERE fabric_switch_name = 'switch-1' 
             AND port = '0' 
             AND datatype = 'TxElements'
             AND DATE(time) = '2016-05-30'
             )
         ) 
         AND DATE(time) = '2016-05-30'
```

This is probably poorly written and does unfortunately use criteria repetition for the subqueries but the concept works as:

> *SubSelect by criteria and* Not *rows where the time column is MAX or MIN time values fitting said criteria*

Reference : https://stackoverflow.com/a/7836444/3536236

So you can then input each day and remove non-earliest and non-latest values. If you want to cycle through the whole table in one fell swoop I would figure you want to create a [`Procedure`](https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/an-introduction-to-stored-procedures-in-mysql-5--net-17843) but I don't know enough to help you much here. However your title says `MYSQL delete all records except first and last for a given date` which implies you will manually run it one date at a time as needed.

## Example:

**Example Set:**

> ```
>    fabric_switch_name |   datatype  |  port  |        time
>  -------------------------------------------------------------------
>        switch-1       |  TxElements |    2   |  2016-05-31 15:00:00
>        switch-1       |  TxElements |    1   |  2016-05-30 22:10:00
>        switch-2       |  TxElements |    0   |  2016-05-30 15:00:00
>        switch-1       |  TxElements |    0   |  2016-05-29 10:20:10
>        switch-1       |  TxElements |    0   |  2016-05-29 05:50:00
>        switch-1       |  TxElements |    0   |  2016-05-29 19:50:00
>        switch-1       |  TxElements |    5   |  2016-05-29 21:50:00
>        switch-1       |  TxElements |    0   |  2016-05-29 20:11:40
> ```

**Result Set:**

> ```
>    fabric_switch_name |   datatype  |  port  |        time
>  -------------------------------------------------------------------
>        switch-1       |  TxElements |    2   |  2016-05-31 15:00:00
>        switch-1       |  TxElements |    1   |  2016-05-30 22:10:00
>        switch-1       |  TxElements |    0   |  2016-05-29 05:50:00
>        switch-2       |  TxElements |    0   |  2016-05-30 15:00:00
>        switch-1       |  TxElements |    5   |  2016-05-29 21:50:00
>        switch-1       |  TxElements |    0   |  2016-05-29 20:11:40
> ```

Comment: ERROR 1093 (HY000): You can't specify target table 'fibre' for update in FROM clause

Comment: Sorry same error.. ERROR 1093 (HY000): You can't specify target table 'fibre' for update in FROM clause

Comment: @nyitguy http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45494/mysql-error-1093-cant-specify-target-table-for-update-in-from-clause

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
DELETE 
FROM collector.fibre  
WHERE fabric_switch_name = 'switch-1'
AND port = '0' 
AND datatype = 'TxElements'
AND time BETWEEN '2016-05-31 00:00:00' AND '2016-05-31 23:59:59' 
AND time NOT IN (
    SELECT MIN(time), MAX(time)
    FROM collector.fibre  
    WHERE fabric_switch_name = 'switch-1'
    AND port = '0' 
    AND datatype = 'TxElements'
    AND time BETWEEN '2016-05-31 00:00:00' AND '2016-05-31 23:59:59' 
)
```

Comment: Whats it give you?

Comment: can you explain what this does? Code only answers are rarely *helpful*

Comment: Well according to his first Response. it doesn't do anything!  lol   I can clarify further for others once the issue is resolved.

Comment: ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'BETWEEN '2016-05-31 00:00:00' AND '2016-05-31 23:59:59' 
)' at line 13

Comment: I was missing the column name time before the second BETWEEN.  I still haven't gotten a chance to sit down and confirm my syntax with some sample data.. but this may be worth trying again.. If it fails I will put together a sample data set and try it.

Answer (score 0):

this query will extract all the record that should be deleted :

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM 
  collector.fibre  f
  INNER JOIN (
    -- create a special table   day   min_time  max_time 
    select 
      date(time) as 'day',
      min(time) as 'min_time',
      max(time) as 'max_time'
    from 
      collector.fibre
     Where fabric_switch_name = 'switch-1'
    group by date(time)
  )  fd on date(f.time) = fd.day  -- join the two table to have a special table see example down  
WHERE 
  fabric_switch_name = 'switch-1' 
  AND port = '0' 
  AND datatype = 'TxElements' 
  -- extract record witch the time is not
  -- the min or the max of that date 
  AND (f.time <> fd.min_time and f.time <> fd.max_time)
```

let suppose this is your date

```
    1           2016-05-31 23:00:00 
    2           2016-05-31 01:00:00
    3           2016-05-31 00:00:00
    4           2016-05-30 10:00:12
    5           2016-05-30 01:00:00
    6           2016-05-30 00:05:00
```

the result of join :

```
    1           2016-05-31 23:00:00         2016-05-31   2016-05-31 00:00:00  2016-05-31 23:00:00  -- this will not be selected in the result
    2           2016-05-31 01:00:00         2016-05-31   2016-05-31 00:00:00  2016-05-31 23:00:00  -- this will be selected because it's not min or max of that day
    3           2016-05-31 00:00:00         2016-05-31   2016-05-31 00:00:00  2016-05-31 23:00:00 
    4           2016-05-30 10:00:00         2016-05-30   2016-05-30 00:05:00  2016-05-30 10:00:12
    5           2016-05-30 01:00:00         2016-05-30   2016-05-30 00:05:00  2016-05-30 10:00:12
    6           2016-05-30 00:00:00         2016-05-30   2016-05-30 00:05:00  2016-05-30 10:00:12
```

Comment: i tried to review my code for syntax error as much as i could hope it help you

Comment: let me know if you try it i love this kind of challenging queries ^_^

Comment: ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'df.min_time' in 'where clause'

Comment: Change the name of sub query to df  i wrote fd sorry dor this

Comment: Ok i edited the query should work fine it was syntax error of sub query name

Comment: I also forget to specify the switch name on subquery i think now is what you want it tell me if you try it

Comment: I m using my phone adda the same condition to the subquery

Comment: It finds over 8K records but how do I delete in the same query? Sorry for the delay response but VPN was not working for me.

Comment: Do you have a primay key on the table ? But i think i deserve up vote for this query

Comment: I do have an Id as the primary key.

Comment: Ok i will edit my answer but after 3 hours from now at least but tell meis the result correct when you test it