# How to select the most up to date (max date) entry in SQL?

Tags: sql, date, group-by, max

I have a database of responses from users. A user is allowed to go back in and change their response to any given question at anytime. What query can I use to best pull in only the most updated response by the user? I know it is something to do with a MAX() function on a date variable, but I get tripped on the details. Here is an example:

```
 USER_ID     SURVEY_NAME    QUESTION_NAME   UPDATE_DATE  RESPONSE
 A1           BIG SURVEY       Q1             01/01/22    BAD  
 A1           BIG SURVEY       Q2             01/01/22    GOOD  
 A1           BIG SURVEY       Q3             01/01/22    OK  
 A1           BIG SURVEY       Q1             01/08/22    GOOD
```

And from the data above, I just want to pull in this:

```
 USER_ID     SURVEY_NAME    QUESTION_NAME   UPDATE_DATE  RESPONSE
 A1           BIG SURVEY       Q2             01/01/22    GOOD  
 A1           BIG SURVEY       Q3             01/01/22    OK  
 A1           BIG SURVEY       Q1             01/08/22    GOOD
```

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sql+top+per+group

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to SELECT by MAX(date)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7836036/how-to-select-by-maxdate)

Comment: Then, when asking SQL questions, please always tag the request with the DBMS you are using. The answer may heavily depend on what your DBMS features.

Comment: @Mushroomator: The request you linked to has a lot of incorrect answers and no accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `row_number()` to find the rows with the latest dates for each (USER_ID,SURVEY_NAME,QUESTION_NAME) triplet:

```
with cte as
(select USER_ID,SURVEY_NAME,QUESTION_NAME,UPDATE_DATE,RESPONSE, 
row_number() 
over(partition by USER_ID,SURVEY_NAME,QUESTION_NAME
order by UPDATE_DATE desc) rn
from mytable)
select USER_ID,SURVEY_NAME,QUESTION_NAME,UPDATE_DATE,RESPONSE
from cte
where rn = 1;
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d6a395100af5cb059b9d5c0b8aa24318)