# MySQL Select Latest Date - Single Table

Tags: mysql

I have a table that looks like this and I want to get the IDs (insp_id) of the newest insp_date for each loc_id.

```
create table insp (
    insp_id int (10),
    loc_id int (11),
    insp_type varchar (150),
    insp_date date ,
    insp_active tinyint (2),
    insp_created timestamp ,
    insp_modified timestamp 
);
```

I tried the "IN" strategy from [Select latest record in table (datetime field)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4788644/select-latest-record-in-table-datetime-field) and others but that gives me double since one loc_id's latest date may be the non-latest for another:

```
SELECT insp_id, loc_id, insp_active, insp_date
FROM insp 
WHERE insp_active = 1 
AND insp_date IN(SELECT MAX(insp_date) FROM insp WHERE insp_active = 1 GROUP BY loc_id)
ORDER BY loc_id ASC, insp_date DESC;
```

I setup a SQL Fiddle but adding various GROUP BY and MAX does not seem to get it. I feel like I need to join on a sub-query or something similar but am not sure at this point.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f95e0/1

Thanks,
Andrew

Comment: For the record, similar thing was raised here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745609/sql-select-only-rows-with-max-value-on-a-column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to retrieve the `MAX` date for each location, and then, the `MAX` insp_id for this date

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT insp.loc_id, max(insp.insp_id)
FROM insp
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT loc_id, max(insp_date) as insp_date
     FROM insp 
     WHERE insp_active = 1 
     GROUP BY loc_id) AS mdate ON mdate.loc_id = insp.loc_id AND 
                                  mdate.insp_date = insp.insp_date
WHERE insp_active = 1 
GROUP BY insp.loc_id
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f95e0/15/0)**:

```
| LOC_ID | MAX(INSP.INSP_ID) |
|--------|-------------------|
|      1 |                 1 |
|      2 |                40 |
|      3 |                48 |
|      4 |                37 |
|      5 |                49 |
|      6 |                39 |
|      7 |                50 |
|      8 |                46 |
```

**UPDATE :**

If there is only one active inspection for a specific date, and this is always the newest that is active, you can just do this :

```
SELECT insp.loc_id, insp.insp_id
FROM insp
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT loc_id, max(insp_date) as insp_date
     FROM insp 
     WHERE insp_active = 1 
     GROUP BY loc_id) AS mdate ON mdate.loc_id = insp.loc_id AND 
                                  mdate.insp_date = insp.insp_date
WHERE insp_active = 1
```

Comment: Saw the update and not always the case for my use but see where it could be for others. Nice idea.

Answer (score 1):

Do a `join` and aggregation:

```
select i.*
from insp i join
     (select loc_id, max(isp_date) as maxid
      from insp
      group by loc_id
     ) lm
     on i.loc_id = lm.loc_id and i.isp_date = lm.maxid;
```

You can still run the risk of duplicates, if the maximum date is repeated for the same location.

Comment: Thanks, I tacked in the insp_active = 1 clause (I forgot to mention that specifically in the ?) and it works great. Looks like the same as @fabien-thesolution... wish I could give equal credit.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT insp_id 
FROM insp
WHERE insp_active = 1
GROUP BY loc_id
ORDER BY insp_date DESC;
```

Comment: Thanks, this did not work right for me even though I feel like it should. Appreciate the thought but think I got it with the other solutions now.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f95e0/18

Verifies that it gives you the same result (albeit in a different order) as the answer you chose

Comment: When I go to that or run the SQL on mine it gives me insp_id 45 for loc_id 2 but the answer I chose correctly gives insp_id 40 for loc_id 2.

Answer (score 0):

Sub-query is the most by-the-book solution, but I used to get away with something less standard, as it was before nesting was allowed in MySQL:

```
select max(concat_ws('|', insp_date, insp_id)) as result, loc_id
from insp
group by loc_id;
```

You'd get something like:

```
2014-01-01|12
2014-02-14|19
...
```

Then you obviously need to split it in your app. Note it's very MySQL-dialect specific and not very performant, but nested queries are not either (or at least used not to be).

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f95e0/23/0

Comment: Thanks, definitely a unique approach to keep in mind for future ideas.